# verify LDAP user password in Java

Tags: java, ldap

I'm attempting to verify a user's password in some Java code:

```
private void bindToLdap(String un, String pw) throws NamingException, AuthenticationException {
    log.debug ("Doing LDAP bind as user");
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, LdapConns.openLdapUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+un+",ou=people,<base OU>");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pw);
    DirContext dctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    log.debug("Context below:");
    log.debug(dctx.getEnvironment().toString());
    dctx.lookup("ou=people");
    log.debug("connection context:");
    log.debug(dctx.getEnvironment().toString());
    log.debug ("Bound as user?");
}
```

Everything I've read so far indicates that I should take an exception when instantiating the DirContext if I've entered a bad password. This is not the case - I get a valid DirContext even if I enter a known bad password. I expect to catch an AuthenticationException at the dctx.lookup, I actually catch a NamingException.

In the debug log, I show:

```
[usermgmt.action.ChangeInternalPassword:bindToLdap:242] Context below:
[usermgmt.action.ChangeInternalPassword:bindToLdap:243] {java.naming.provider.url=ldaps://<ldap server>:636/, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.security.principal=nononyen_test, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming, java.naming.security.credentials=fubar!}
```

How do I verify that the password is actually correct? Do I need to perform a search on the LDAP db after binding to take the exception?

The LDAP database is OpenLDAP.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the code calling this method? An empty catch block or something similar

Answer (score 3):

To determine whether an authentication ID and password is correct, applications must establish a connection to the directory server and then transmit a bind request and examine the response. The bind response from the server will contain an integer result code indicating the success or failure of the bind request, and may also contain response controls with some extra information about the status of the user entry.

Comment: +1. The LDAP `bind` operation corresponds to the JNDI `reconnect()` operation.